# Как получить гарантированно верную высоту страницы? documentElement.offsetHeight и getBoundingClientRect() работают не всегда корректно

Tags: javascript, dom

Столкнулся с проблемой:

На некоторых страницах `document.documentElement .offsetHeight` и `.getBoundingClientRect()` возвращают не полную высоту страницы, а фактически клиентскую часть окна.

При изменении размера окна указанные показатели меняются

Пробовал `body` вместо `documentElement` - то же самое.

При этом есть элементы, которые по данным `getBoundingClientRect` имеют больший размер.

Браузер Firefox.

Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда, как только задам вопрос в сети, ответ находится сам...

Нужно использовать `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`, а лучше для надежности выбирать максимальный показатель:

```
Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,
  document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,
  document.documentElement.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight,
  document.documentElement.clientHeight
)
```

Comment: Писал то же самое и не успел) Но у меня есть чувство, что если не нужно поддерживать легаси браузеры, то можно проще